# Pan gesture translation being reset between should-begin and handler (with state began) on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture recognizer to drag a panel up, down, left, or right. When the direction of the pan is not possible I don't allow the recognizer to begin so that the touches can go to other UI elements within the panel.

However, on iOS7 the translation sometimes gets reset between `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` and my gesture handler `handlePan:`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGR
{
    CGPoint trans = [panGR translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"should begin trans: (%.2f, %.2f)", trans.x, trans.y);
    ...
```

This logs: `should begin trans: (18.00, 0.00)`

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGR
{
    CGPoint trans = [panGR translationInView:self.view];

    switch(panGR.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"handlePan began trans: (%.2f, %.2f)", trans.x, trans.y);
            ...
```

This logs: `handlePan began trans: (0.00, 0.00)`

Which means the shared code to determine the direction of the pan (right, in this case) works in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` and allows the gesture to begin, but then can't be determined in `handlePan:` when the `state` is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Is this a bug in iOS7 or has the behaviour deliberately changed to accommodate new gesture types? Also, can anyone suggest a good way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is always setting the translation to (0,0) after reaching the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state - since even the slightest translation is recognized it's designed to work as a trigger only (if you set up large threshold for beginning the recognition like (50,50) you will obviously get a "lag" in UI behavior - as a workaround I would suggest to store the value of the translation and then use a UIView animation to pan the object more smoothly). You should use the `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` for updating the translation, and `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` for setting the end point of the pan.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This translation reset happens between `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and the handler with state `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. I think it's a bug in iOS7

Comment: what I had in mind by writing "after reaching the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`" is that this resetting happens before the handler is called, isn't it? I understand the problem and ran some code to reproduce it - I agree with you that this behavior is very confusing and in some cases may cause trouble, e.g. in a situation when your implementation of `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` returns `YES` only when relatively large (i.e. distances that can be seen on screen, like your `(18.00, 0.00)`) transition occurs. Which I understood is the case?

Answer (score -1):

You can determine the direction in `handlePan:` by checking if the horizontal translation is higher or lower than 0. But at the end of `handlePan:` you do need to reset the `CGPoint` of the translation as the new reference for the next translation.

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGR
{
    CGPoint translation = [gr translationInView:self.view];
    if (translation.x > 0) {
        //Direction: Right
    } else if (translation.x < 0) {
        //Direction: Left
    }


    [gr setTranslation:CGPointZero
                inView:self.view];
}
```